# Como trazer uma relação de cidade em funcionario?

Tags: c#

Tenho essa model

```
public class Funcionario
  {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Nome do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings =false)]
        [Display(Name ="Nome")]
        public String nome { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data de Nascimento do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "CPF do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "CPF")]
        public long cpf { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cidade do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
        public virtual int cidade { get; set; }
    }
```

e essa outra

```
public class Cidade
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome da cidade é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name="Nome")]
        public String nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Veja que a classe Funcionario recebe Cidade e preciso mostrar o nome da cidade no Grid e não apenas o código. Então pergunto: Devo trazer em funcionario uma collection de Cidade? E como fica na model Cidade? um **virtual int ????**

Comment: Quando eu postei, já me deram downvote sem ler, como são rápidos

Comment: Cara, você tem bastante dúvida sobre C# e ASP.NET MVC, e dúvidas meio básicas, como são com certa frequência, te aconselho a ler livros e ver cursos sobre a tecnologia, tenho certeza que você não vai precisar ficar perdendo tempo com esse nível de pergunta.

Comment: Nunca sei se essas perguntas são sérias ou um tipo de teste quando quem posta é um usuário com tantos pontos de reputação

Comment: Ainda mais quando o apelido e a tag principal do usuário dão a entender que já utiliza muito .net

Answer (score 1):

Depende de como você deseja seu relacionamento, se você estiver seguindo a linha que um Funcionário está em uma Cidade e uma Cidade possui vários funcionários, o relacionamento seria o seguinte:

```
public class Funcionario
{
    //Essa propriedade representa a chave estrangeira da cidade
    public int IDCidade { get; set; }

    //Essa propriedade representa a entidade da cidade
    [ForeignKey("IDCidade")]
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
}

public class Cidade
{
    public Cidade()
    {
        Funcionarios = new List<Funcionario>();
    }

    //Essa propriedade representa a coleção de funcionários
    public ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Vou deixar um link para você com muitas informações sobre as configurações do Entity Framework. Acho um site muito interessante e útil. Link: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx

Comment: Corrigi a model de funcionário, pois havia me esquecido de alterar o tipo da Cidade. Estava `int Cidade`, mas o certo é `Cidade Cidade`